# Can't update or add new contact photo Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I can't understand why it works on emulator but not on real device.

Please help!!!

Here I'm getting contact id by phone number

```
    ContentResolver crFull = context.getContentResolver(); 
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(PhoneNumberFormatter.GetOnlyNumbers(((Contact)recipients.get(k)).GetContactPhoneNumber())));
    Cursor cursor = crFull.query(lookupUri, new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID }, null, null, null);
    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
```

Here I'm converting new image from Base64

```
    String base64Image = json.getString("PhotoBase64");
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    ByteArrayOutputStream streamy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, streamy); 
    byte[] photo = streamy.toByteArray();
```

Here I'm checking if contact already has image

```
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(crFull, uri);
```

If has

```
    int photoRow = -1;
    String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + id + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " =='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
    Cursor cursorr = crFull.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null, null);
    int idIdx = cursorr.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
    if (cursorr.moveToFirst()) {
        photoRow = cursorr.getInt(idIdx);
    }

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID + " == " + Integer.toString(photoRow), new String[] {})
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA15, photo)
    .build());

    try {
            crFull.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {

    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If not

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo)
    .build());

    try 
    {
        crFull.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {

    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Update and Insert Works only on Emulator. If I launch it on real device nothing updates and inserts in images. Also on real device i have no exceptions.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get exceptions? Is the result not as expected? Does neither of these methods (update as well as insert) work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();


ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                            .newUpdate(
                                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withSelection(
                                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ? AND "
                                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = ?",
                                    new String[] {
                                            contactid,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE })
                            .withValue(Photo.DATA15, b).build());
```